# TypeError: geturl() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: python, mechanize

I have made a script in Python, Mechanize, that should register automatically on specific web page.

Code:

```
import mechanize 

br = mechanize.Browser() 

response = br.open("https://arkhamnetwork.org/community/register")

br.addheaders = [("User-agent","Mozilla/5.0")] 

gitbot = br.open("https://arkhamnetwork.org/community/register") 

br.select_form(nr=1)

br.set_all_readonly(False)

br.form.set_value("test", nr=0)

br.method = "POST"

response = br.submit()

print response.geturl('http://arkhamnetwork.org/community/register/register')
```

Whenever i execute script, i get this error:

`TypeError: geturl() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`

What should be the problem?

Comment: You are providing self and anther argument by calling it on instance, that is why it is Type erroring you with it. I can't find good docs about this module, but I think it takes only self as parameter.

Comment: What do i need to do, to fix the problem?

Comment: Try `print response.geturl()`

Comment: Thanks! it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some (fairly rudimentary) documentation [here](http://www.joesourcecode.com/Documentation/mechanize0.2.5/mechanize._mechanize.Browser-class.html) which tells you how to use the `geturl()` method:

> `geturl(self)`
>
> Get URL of current document.

In general, when your error tells you you're passing one too many arguments, it's often because you're forgetting about the fact that instance methods of an object implicitly pass `self` as the first parameter.